# Ionic 4/5: exit from the app pressing back button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to exit from the app when the back button is pressed only in a certain page; in particular, let's say I have I have the *app.component.ts* and I have a page called *HomePage*. In *app-routing.module.ts* I have this routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: './public/home/home.module#HomePageModule' }
];
```

So whever the user opens the app, it will see the *HomePage* as first page. If the user presses the back button, now it reloads the same page forever; I want to catch that pressing and exit the app. I've tried to use this in *home.page.ts*, but nothing happens:

```
backButtonSubscription: any;
this.backButtonSubscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(async () => {
console.log('lets exit!');
  navigator['app'].exitApp();
  });
```

Even the console.log is printed, as if the event is not caught. I've also tried with this:

```
 this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(99999, () => {
        navigator['app'].exitApp();
 });
```

but the result is the same, so I'm wondering how it can be solved. I've found a lots of questions online, but there's no explanation that seems to solve this issue or to give a workaround.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you post the code in html for back button?

Comment: There's no HTML code, because it's supposed to catch the back button of the device

Answer (score 2):

if you are using ionic 4 angular . try this
in **AppComponent -> initializeApp**
add

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, () => {
navigator[‘app’].exitApp();
});
```

here is an example

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, () => {
        navigator['app'].exitApp();
       
     });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case im using capacitor (ionic 5), try this if you're using capacitor too

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { App } = Plugins;

initializeApp() {
  App.addListener('backButton', () => {
    App.exitApp();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ionic 5.
Another option its to use `Platform`, for me it woks well in case of using tabs:

p.s. better to use "init" service instead of app.component.ts to keep app init flow clean and obvious

```
constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private router: Router
) {
    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(-1, () => {
        const url = this.router.url;
    
        if (url === '/tabs/not-home') {
            this.router.navigate(['/tabs/home']);
        } else if (url === '/tabs/home') {
            App.exitApp();
        }
    });
}
```